# How to take jenkins backup before installing new plugins

Tags: jenkins

I am having a stable Jenkins instance with all the plugins and jobs running fine on on-prem slaves servers. Now I am planning to use cloud EC2(AWS) as slaves servers. But for that I have to install some new plugins. So I am planning to take a backup of my stable instance with all the plugins.

Could some suggest me a good way to take a back-up so if anythings goes wrong I will get my stable instance as it is.

I could use:

```
http://jenkins:8080/pluginManager/api/json?tree=plugins[shortName,version]&pretty=true
```

But is there any better way because it will not store the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of your %JENKINS_HOME% directory which you can use to restore to go back to a working stable installation of Jenkins. This directory includes jobs, plugins, security etc.